# Problem when I delete an item (ObservableCollection) from a ListView in Xamarin

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, observablecollection, imagesource

I will put the code fragments and at the end the result of the problem that I have.

EvidenciaItemVideModel.cs

```
private string caption;
private ImageSource thumb;     

public ImageSource Thumb
{
    get { return this.thumb; }
    set { SetValue(ref this.thumb, value); }
}

public string Caption
{
    get { return this.caption; }
    set { SetValue(ref this.caption, value); }
}
```

The Listview is associated with the following property.

```
private ObservableCollection<EvidenciaItemViewModel> evidencias;
public ObservableCollection<EvidenciaItemViewModel> Evidencias
{
    get { return this.evidencias; }
    set { SetValue(ref this.evidencias, value); }
}
```

Fragment where I add an item to the listview

```
    if (this.file != null)
    {
        this.Evidencias.Add(new EvidenciaItemViewModel {
            Caption = "Archivo " + (this.Evidencias.Count + 1),
            Thumb = this.ImageSource
        });                
    }
```

The process to remove an item is as follows.

```
public void RemoveEvidencia(EvidenciaItemViewModel obj)
{
    this.Evidencias.Remove(obj);
}
```

Everything works correctly, the problem I have when I delete an item; for example: if I have 4 items and I eliminate the number 2, the image of the last element is replicated until the position of the next element of the elimination. I add a couple of images to show what I indicate.

[ListView loaded before removing item](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LNvET.png)

[Item removed, the image of the last element is replicated in the ones that follow it after the deleted element.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EpWGK.png)

Comment: What is the code for deleting the button method?

Answer (score 0):

Delete button click method should be like as bellow:

```
void OnDeleteClicked(Object sender, MyEventArgs args)
{
  Button btn = sender as Button;
  var evidenciaItemVideModel = btn.BindingContext as EvidenciaItemVideModel;
  EvidenciaVideModelInstance.RemoveEvidencia(evidenciaItemVideModel);
}
```

Then EvidenciaVideModel's `RemoveEvidencia` can work:

```
public void RemoveEvidencia(EvidenciaItemViewModel obj)
{
   Evidencias.Remove(obj);
}
```